# WPF OnKeyDown Alt+Key combination generates a beep sound

Tags: wpf, input

In *WPF* Controls, a beep sound is generated on Alt+Key keyboard combination.

I have some code which handle specific Alt+Key shortcuts in an override implementation of:

> void UIElement.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e);

- Setting **e.Handled = true** doesn't mute the sound.
- Neither does not calling **base.OnKeyDown(e);**
- OnPreviewKeyDown behaves in the same way.

How to suppress this sound ?
*WinForms* apparently had **e.SuppressKeyPress = true** but that doesn't exist anymore in *WPF*.

Answer (score 0):

to handle this you should use different event

```
private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

to know about this event ref :[URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2)